# Promise<Employee>[] is not assignable to parameter of type Employee[]

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to load my Collection of Employees from a Firestore Database and for every Employee I want to load a 'Workday' which is a Document of a Subcollection of 'Employees'. This is my code:

```
loadEmployees() {
    return new Promise<Employee[]>(resolve => {
        this.db.collection('Employees').snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(changes => changes.map(async a => {
                const employee = a.payload.doc.data() as Employee;
                employee.id = a.payload.doc.id;
                employee.workday = await this.loadWorkday(employee);    // <-- returns a Promise<Workday>

                return employee;
            }))
        ).subscribe(
            employees => {
                resolve(employees); // Error: <--- Promise<Employee>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Employee[]
            }
        );
    });
}
```

But I get the Syntax Error `Promise<Employee>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Employee[]`. I don't know how I can get the `Employee[]` of the `Promise<Employee>[]` so I can call resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.resolve()` to lift your constant/variable `employees` into a `Promise`.

Use `reduce()` before `subscribe()` to collate your `employees` into an array of `Employee`.

If each `employee` is returned as a `Promise`, then unwrap that promise using a `flatMap()` with `Rx.Observable.from()` before `reduce()`'ing.